# How do I append DOM in chain reaction using jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, append

how do I play with dom with jquery again after the dom is appended by using jquery?
I guess they don't work since they are appended after "$(document).ready();"

for example:

```
$('.kim2').on('click', function() {
    var ok = $(this).next();
    var ok2 = $(this);
    $('#content').empty().append(ok2, ok);
});
```

html :

```
<div class="con">
    <div class="kim2">사고 종류<br />(택일)</div>
    <div id="d" class="kim2b"><div id="d1" class="kim2bb">원동기장치 <br />자전거사고</div>
    <div id="d2" class="kim2bb"><p>자동차 사고</p></div></div>
</div>
```

Now, I click 'kim2 class' so 'kim2 div' and it's next() 'kim2b div' would replace original '#content div', however I can't anymore append to new #content div using jquery after I have them replaced with the old ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue is here that you use empty()

From [.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) docs

```
If you want to remove elements without destroying their data or event
handlers (so they can be re-added later), use .detach() instead.
```

```
$('div.kim2bb, div.kim2bc').on('click', // <--
```

You either need to use delegation - or detach the children elements instead of using empty to remove them

```
$('#content').on('click','div.kim2bb, div.kim2bc', function(){
        // your code here
});
```

or change this

```
$('#content').on('click', '.kim2', function () {
    var ok = $(this).next();
    var ok2 = $(this);
    $('#content').empty().append(ok2, ok); //<-- you lose the event handlers here using .empty()
});
```

to

```
$('#content').on('click', '.kim2', function () {
    var ok = $(this).next();
    var ok2 = $(this);
    $('#content').children().detach().end().append(ok2, ok);
});
```

Comment: np :)  Always glad to help

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('click', '.kim2', function() {
    var ok = $(this).next();
    var ok2 = $(this);
    $('#content').empty().append(ok2, ok);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/ (See *Direct and delegated events* section)

Comment: they are not working 
I think it's because appended dom was not there when (document).ready(); , aren't they?